# Using variable in writing a jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to write a function of jquery using a variable:

```
var t_id=24;
$("#"+t_id).val()="";
```

which does not make it a valid function. any ideas on achieving it?

Comment: `$("#"+t_id).val("")`. Why did you think you could **assign** to the result of a function call? Please read the **documentation**: http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2. You might also benefit from reading a JavaScript tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: `val()` is a getter, it gets something from the jquery object. If you pass it an argument, it becomes a setter and changes something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$("#"+t_id).val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

correct syntax to set value is:

```
$("#"+t_id).val("value");
```